# Capacitor Back to Super Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, parallel, capacitance, series, coil

I am attempting to make a smaller coil gun (pistol). I do not have a super capacitor. However, I have about x400, 10v, 2200uF capacitors. Am I able to make a bank of a sort and get the same effect as a large capacitor with many small ones?

Comment: Google ESL. Crunch some numbers. Think about it.

Comment: If you're talking about coils... shouldn't you use inductors?

Comment: Have you done any maths or calculations?

Comment: I am wandering if I will get the same effect as a large capacitor